# Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not specified

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have created a basic spring boot application from **SPRING INITIALIZR** with the Web, MongoDB and JPA dependencies.

When I try to run the spring boot application I am getting the following exception:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-25 16:27:02.807 ERROR 16256 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not specified and no embedded datasource could be auto-configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following situation:
If you want an embedded database like H2, HSQL or Derby, please add it in the Classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it since no profiles were currently active.
```

In application.properties file I am having the following configuration:

```
server.port=8081
spring.data.mongodb.database=TestDatabase
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

**Versions which I use:**
Spring : 5.0.4,
MongoDB : 3.6,
Spring Boot: 2.0

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Since you have added both mongodb and data-jpa dependencies in your pom.xml file, it was creating a dependency conflict like below

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Try removing jpa dependency and run. It should work fine.

Comment: Yes that was my problem. I have removed the JPA dependency and it works fine now. Thank you.

Comment: Please note also `spring-boot-starter-batch` introduces a dependency to jdbc which activates this same error

Comment: Yes that solved my problem. In my case was `org.postgresql:postgresql` and `data-jpa`. Just exclude `data-jpa` and all is fine.

Comment: Would it have created an error if I had `data-jpa` and `mysql-connector-java` in my pom.xml?

Comment: I hided the mongo db dependency but still had the same problem.

Comment: I guess you should not remove the mongo dependancy instead remove the data-jpa dependancy.

Comment: Thanks for answering it helps a lot I too resolved the issue by your given answer.

Comment: For mongodb: use mongo dependency

Comment: I had this issue when I was switching my Spring project from Postgres to MongoDB. If you are using IntelliJ, please remember to do a MAVEN SYNC after editing your `pom.xml`!

Comment: I had been grappling with the same issue for a good 2-3 hours, trying various AI tools, but none of them provided the answer I needed. Then, I stumbled upon your solution, and my reaction was a mix of surprise and disbelief. It made me question whether these AI systems can truly replace human expertise. Thanks a lot, Man !!!

Answer (score 63):

Go to resources folder where the application.properties is present, update the below code in that.

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: I have got this problem even i didn't use jpa and mongodb dependencies together in my pom.xml... So i am getting it cuz `spring-boot-starter-batch` dependency. Can you please explain why this setting is work ?

Comment: It worked, but then i got error when sending request from client side: `blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Comment: @AdirD That has nothing to do with the issue at hand, you need to set your server to accept CORS requests

Answer (score 22):

Add the line below in **application.properties** file under resource folder and restart your application.

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this error simply because I misspelled the `spring.datasource.url` value in the **application.properties** file and I was using postgresql:

**Problem was:**
`jdbc:postgres://localhost:<port-number>/<database-name>`

**Fixed to:**
`jdbc:postgresql://localhost:<port-number>/<database-name>`

NOTE: the difference is `postgres` & `postgresql`, the two are 2 different things.

Further causes and solutions may be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-failed-to-configure-data-source)

Answer (score 2):

Seems there is missing MongoDB driver. Include the following dependency to `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already have this dependency in my pom.xml file. Still failing.

Comment: it failed for me too with spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb & spring-batch-starter

Answer (score 1):

your dependency based on data is trying to find their respective entities which one has not been created, comments the dependencies based on data and runs the app again.

```
<!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred when you are putting JPA dependencies in your spring-boot configuration file like in maven or gradle.
The solution is: [Spring-Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database)

You have to specify the DB connection string and driver details in application.properties file. This will solve the issue.
This might help to someone.

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is here after **facing this issue

when "project.jar" is generated**

while
every thing is fine when i the project is run in IDE / STS (spring tool suit).
here is a way out:

unnecessary spaces " " in the "application.yml" file can cause this.

```
server:
  port: 8085


spring:
 datasource:
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb
  username: root
  password: root
  driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
 jpa:
   hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update
   show-sql: true
   database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
 application:
  name: STUDENT-SERVICE
```

instead of tweaking my "application.yml" file
i simply moved all my statements in "application.yml" file to
"application.properties" file and formatted the statements like required in ".properties".

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format.sql=true

spring.application.name=student-service

server.port=8085
```

**and voilà**

Comment: I also faced with the problem, after changed packaging from war to jar. I have an application.properties file which has a profile value and then application-profileName.properties file is used to get db connection parameters. Interestingly, when works after changed back to war.

Answer (score 0):

Add your dependencies like mongodb,web,jpa. Delete/clear the remainings.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

In gradle build i simply:

`compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')`

removed

```
**`compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')`**
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Bhabadyuti Bal give us a good answer, in gradle you can use :

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa' 
compile 'com.h2database:h2'
```

in test time :

```
testCompile 'org.reactivecommons.utils:object-mapper:0.1.0'
testCompile 'com.h2database:h2'
```

Answer (score -1):

adding org.apache.derby dependency solved my issue.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem when I simply mistyped my jdbc url in application.properties. Hope this helps someone:
before:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc://localhost:3306/test
```

after:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
```